# Unique random token generation in grails

Tags: grails, random, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am new with grails and on my web application i want to generate a random token with 15 characters length along with username. And tokens must be unique.

All characters from a-z and 0-9 can be use, but no special characters.
I have tried to generate random token with

```
def generator = {String alphabet, int n -> new Random().with { (1..n).collec alphabet[ nextInt( alphabet.length() ) ] }.join() }} generator( (('A'..'Z')+('0'..'9')).join(), 9 )
```

but how can i append username infront of token like "JayKay586464ASDHH445"

Comment: Could you explain in details? from my side username + token should work :)

Comment: unique random token is must for my app. so i need to append username along with token genarated.
but how can i append username along with generator in this case

Comment: you can just use operator "+" to concatenate strings

Comment: Shame you [can't just use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates) `UUID.randomUUID()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? The username holds the original username without the token, token is the 15 character token and uTok is the username with the token

```
def generator = { String alphabet, int n ->
  new Random().with {
    (1..n).collect { alphabet[ nextInt( alphabet.length() ) ] }.join()
  }
}

def token = generator( (('A'..'Z')+('0'..'9')).join(), 15 )

def username = "JayKay"

def uTok = "${username}${token}"

println "==>${uTok}<=="
```

Answer (score 9):

`String confirmCode= UUID.randomUUID().toString()` use this codeto generate token,
 then use "+" to concatenate string